# ASP MVC DropDownListFor not selecting value from list

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a view like this:

```
@{
    var jobTitles = new List<string>
    {
        "Title1",
        "Title2",
        "Title3",
    };
    var titlesList = new SelectList(jobTitles, Model.Title);
}
```

Now titlesList is a SelectList that contains the selected value from the Model. I've debugged this and ensured it is correct.

Then later on in the same view, I have the following Razor:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Title, titlesList, "Select an option", new { @class = "form-control", @required = "required" })
```

And when my view renders in this case, the selected option in the dropdown is "Select an option". I've debugged the list and the selected value is indeed the correct one in memory, but the DropDownListFor is not displaying it as such.

Edit:

I am using this same principle on another EditorTemplate like so (and it works):

```
var types = new List<string>
{
    "Set Up",
    "Show Start",
    "Break Down"
};
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TimeSlotTask, new SelectList(types), "Select an option", new { @class = "form-control", @required = "required" })
```

I realize the SelectList is initialized differently in these 2 examples, but I've tried both ways in each and it's not working in the first example.

Like I said, I've debugged the Controller and the Razor and the value of the property on the Model that I'm looking for is correctly set and identical to the value in the list the SelectList is bound to.

Edit #2 (Templates)

My master view has the following snippet:

```
    <span id="addAttendeeButton" class="btn btn-success btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span><span id="removeAttendeeButton" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></span>
    <ul id="attendees" style="list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Attendees)
    </ul>
```

With some jQuery to handle adding new items to the #attendees

```
        $("#addAttendeeButton").click(function() {
            var id = $('#attendees > li').length;
            $.get('@Url.Action("CreateAttendee")/' + id, function(data) {
                $('#attendees').append(data);
            });
        });
        $("#removeAttendeeButton").click(function() {
            $('#attendees li:last').remove();
        });
```

Then the EditorTemplate for the Attendee is:

```
@{
    var jobTitles = new List<string>
    {
        "Account Manager",
        "Application Engineer",
        "Customer Care",
        "Sales Engineer",
        "Marketing Manager",
        "Product Manager",
        "Trade Show Coordinator",
    };
    var titlesList = new SelectList(jobTitles);
}

<li>
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="input-group-lg">
                <label>Name</label>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="input-group-lg">
                <label>Job Titless</label>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Title, titlesList, "Select an option", new { @class = "form-control", @required = "required" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="input-group-lg">
                <label>Show Lead</label>
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Lead, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

The problem is the DropDownListFor in the EditorTemplate. When I load an existing Entity, it doesn't select the value from the Model. However, when I simply use a foreach loop in Razor to iterate over the collection of "Attendees", the Title property is properly set and displayed correctly (simply using a  to display it).

So I know it's being set and saved correctly to the model from the dropdown, but when re-rendering the Edit view, where there is a dropdown present, the value is not being selected in the dropdown pointing to the Model.

Comment: show you controller, also data should not be on your view

Comment: The controller simply grabs the entity from the DB, with this property set (as I said, I debugged it and it is correctly set), and passes it to the view. Also, this data being in the view, whether 'standard' or not, doesn't mean whats there shouldn't be working.

Comment: Are you sure the value of property `Title` is one of those 3 values?. Note also it can be just `var titlesList = new SelectList(jobTitles)` - the second parameter of `SelectList` will be ignored anyway

Comment: 100% positive. I do however have another dropdown bound to a different list, on the same page (using a different editor template) that correctly selects the value from the dropdown when the view is rendered. The list is setup exactly the same (within razor), and bound exactly the same with a DropDownListFor.

Comment: You mentioned an `EditorTemplate` - are you doing something in a loop?

Comment: Edit #2 has been added to the original post.

Comment: Is `Title` a string or a complex object? In the latter case it won't work...

Comment: Note, if I change the HTML type from DropDownListFor to EditorFor, the value of the title is preserved and displayed. It's only when I change it to DropDownListFor does it break.